# How do I get what I want with Math.round in JAVA?

Tags: java, rounding

I'm using this code to round a value:

```
Math.round(x * 100) / 100.0;
```

But it doesn't return what I need.

E.g.: `x = 83.5067`

What I want: `83.51`
What I get: `83.5`

Comment: `double`s don't _have_ a number of decimal digits; they have a number of binary digits, which is _not_ the same thing.  If you want a specific number of decimal digits, use `BigDecimal` or convert to a `String` with a `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: `Math.round` returns `83.51` in that case. Why do you think it's `83.5`?

Comment: Hmm, well. A JUnit Test expects 83.51 as an output. But it's 83.5.
So I think it's this part of the code which doesn't work well, but you're saying it returns the expected number.
I need to have a look on my code, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your output is a double it will work fine look [here](http://ideone.com/YrmSXp)

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    double a = Math.round(83.5067 * 100) / 100.0;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

will print `83.51`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use formatted output instead of rounding. Like,

```
double x = 83.5067;
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", x);
```

but, to do the requested rounding you might use

```
double x = 83.5067;
x = Math.round(x * 100);
x /= 100;
System.out.println(x);
```

Both output

```
83.51
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `BigDecimal` for these kind of operations.

```
// Round it
final BigDecimal myRoundedNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(83.5067).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

// If you need it as a double
final double d = myRoundedNumber.doubleValue();
```

The `setScale`-method is flexible and you can set the number of decimals and the rounding mode you require.